# Non-inverting op amp problem

Tags: lm386, non-inverting

I have problem with an lm386 op amp in an non-inverting configuration. For the resistors, I take two equal resistors so i set a gain of 2. When i put a signal of 3.3 volts on the non-inverting pin, i should get 6.6 volts on the output on the op amp, but i get totaly different measuring. I have also measured the voltage on the inverting and non-inverting pins and i do not get the same voltage but i should. Also when no voltage is connected on the non-inverting pin (when its grounded) i am not getting 0 volts on the output, but i am getting zero point something volts. I have also tried to change the ic or the resistors but it didnt worked. So now i wanted to ask am i makeing a mistake or the mistake is in the ic. Every answer is welcome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please post a schematic.

Comment: 1. What op-amp are you using? Is it rail-to-rail on both input and output? 2. What are the power supply connections?

Comment: Also, does your "LM386" tag actually relate to your question? LM386 is not an op-amp.

Comment: An LM386 is not an opamp. You can't wire it up like one and expect it to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you see a big difference between inverting and non-inverting terminals, one of three things may be happening:

```
- the open-loop gain is degenerate, so the error voltage cannot be reduced further
- the output is saturated, limited by the supply rails
- the measurement equipment was affecting the circuit
```

LM386 is an audio amplifier, not an op amp, even though it has some superficial similarity.

According to [LM386 datasheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjoj-CPzujdAhXVN30KHeC_AbwQFjAVegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw3HImAhjX6EOw4Q5pZIccde), the open-loop gain `Av` is only 26dB i.e. 20V/V. This is far from the ideal opamp where Av is considered near infinite.

Consequence of this reduced open-loop gain is that there will be significant difference between the inverting and non-inverting inputs, as you observed.

Comment: You were nice not to say so, but the OP is miss-using the LM386 in terms of its intended function and design. It cannot be treated as an op-amp. Coupling capacitors mean it is intended for a single ended power supply. +1